# replace one with zero in identity matrix | Numpy |

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am learning Numpy. How do i get the expected output from identity matrix

**identity matrix**

```
1, 0, 0
0, 1, 0
0, 0, 1
```

**Expected Output :**

```
1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, however assuming you have a matrix of zeros with 1's on the diagonal and want to have all zeros but the first element:

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0],
              [0,1,0],
              [0,0,1]])
np.fill_diagonal(a, 0)
a[0,0] = 1
```

output:

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: can you explain what actually the `a,0` doing and even the `a[0,0]=1`

Comment: Sorry, `a` is the input array ;)